# Ask the user for their name and a number, display their name that number of times

Tags: python

I'm working through these challenges which have been set for me to do, I am quite new to python, and I seriously need some help, the question asks me to ask the user for their name, then a number and display their name that a number of times, using for loops, hope someone can help.

```py
word = input('What is your name ')
number = int(input('Enter a number ')
for i in word:
        print(i)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your post with your code.

Comment: I've added it if you click on code so far.

Comment: Please add the code as text in the question, rather than as a link to an image. If it's text, we can copy and paste it to run it ourselves if we want to, which means you're more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @JB14 Please paste your code text in the questions and format it using the code  { } button. Your for loop is not correct. >>> for i in range(number): >>> print(word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For number times print the string in word variable (Also close the brackets here  `number = int(input('Enter a number ')` :

```
word = input('What is your name ')
number = int(input('Enter a number'))

for i in range(number):
    print(word)
```

To print each letter in the word

```
word = input('What is your name ')

for letter in word:
    print(letter)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been asked to display each letter on a different line, how could I integrate this into that program

Comment: @JB14 I edited my answer above. Please select as answered if it was helpful